# What is firmware timeout?

Tags: linux, firmware, sysfs

I found a file `/sys/class/firmware/timeout`, and this file contains just one word **60**. Is this timeout related to `bootloader` like `GRUB timeout`? What is the practical use of it?

Comment: I believe the timeout tag is focused on the timeout command; I added some other relevant tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not related to any bootloader at all.

When a driver uses the kernel's common firmware loading infrastructure to load a firmware file, the kernel can either load the file directly from the standard `/lib/firmware` directory tree, or it can optionally start an user-space process to handle the firmware load.

This user-space process used to be part of the `hotplug` subsystem, then a part of `udev`, but I think it's currently deprecated and the in-kernel version is the primary means of loading firmware for any drivers.

If the entire firmware load operation takes more than the number of seconds specified in `/sys/class/firmware/timeout`, the operation will be considered failed. As a result, the driver that requested the firmware will most likely fail too.

More details can be found in the [Documentation/firmware_class](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/firmware_class/README) directory of the Linux kernel source code package.